# A practical guide to Jewish neighborhoods and communities in Israel

Tags: product-recommendation, communities, cities, aliya-laaretz, state-of-israel

In the interest of fulfilling the Torah imperative to live in the Lnd of Israel, can anyone recommend a guide to Jewish neighborhoods and communities in Israel that includes information on as many as possible among the following categories?

- good for families with young children
- good for Americans
- good for observant (frum), pro-Zionist Jews
- good for artists

Comment: Might I suggest contacting [Nefesh B'Nefesh](http://www.nbn.org.il)?  Their website has a [community guide](http://www.nbn.org.il/aliyahpedia/community-a-housing/community-guide-beta-listings/12225-intro-to-communities.html).

Comment: (Also being afraid of Israelis or antipathetic towards Hareidim might make the move rather challenging.)

Comment: I think this is in the category of "Not Constructive" (while that category still exists)

Comment: @Seth J I don't think it's fear -I think it's a question of how antipahtehic towards new Americans some Israelis 'might' be and finding a comfort zone for my wife and kids. Personally, I have roughed it through anything I have lived on beans and rice, sometimes less. Re hareidim, well could any modern person last in monsey let alone Chariediland they are my fellow jews, but it would be stiffling. I think the link you provided get's it done as an answer for me.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Yeah, I definitely think it's one or the other.

Comment: @seekingclarity I would certainly not be considered Charedi by any measure, but I lived in B'nei B'rak for a while and loved it!

Comment: @Daniel, I think I'm more concerned about being around anyone who can foster creativity I just know in American Yeshivish circles it's not there, and having cheap or communal rental space to use as an art studio would help, Chariedi neighborhood or not.

Comment: seekingclarity, @Daniel, I have cousins who are very much not Charedi (to say the least) who live in Williamsburg. And love it.

Comment: @SethJ I don't think it's any ill I have towards anyone's brand of frumkiet, I just would like to be around some jews who like some art/music (real music) with their spirituality. haven't found it.

Comment: What if you change it to something more general, like: "Guides for religious Americans making aliyah"

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, why make it more general? These are reasonable characteristics to look for in a community, and only one of them is at all uncommon. It's conceivable that some community guides are better at providing information that addresses these concerns than others.

Comment: The last one is the zinger, isn't it Why does being frum make it so hard to be around authentically creative people? -I figure if I am to take the plunge and make major life adjustments -the biggest being working a six day week, earning less and living tighter, then I might as well try to see if there can be a place where one can be frum and amongst other creatives. It's almost impossible in the US -Our culture does not reward originality or self expression and sometimes I think it's discouraged.

Comment: Query: how many different meanings does the phrase "pro-Zionist" have, and which one do you intend?

Comment: @TRiG "pro-Zionist" means (to me) the support of the state of Israel's existence -secular or otherwise, it's laws and a person's civic duty as a citizen of Israel to serve in the army or perform some kind or national service as required,

Comment: Tzfat suits all your categories